# Saving HTMLPurifier config in a separate file (using Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, configuration, htmlpurifier

Is it possible to save the config for HTMLPurifier in a separate file so that I don't have to enter the config lines every time I create an instance?

I am using the standalone version as follows:

```
library/HTMLPurifier.php
library/standalone
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the config into codeigniter config file,
create a wrapper class that wrap around HTMLPurifier,
and putting all your config setting into constructor, like this :-

```
class Purifier extends HTMLPurifier
{
  public function __construct()
  {
     // call parent::__construct
     // load and set your configuration
     // seq might affect the logic, you might want to reverse it
  }
```